# Get razor to interpret "checked" as a html attribute instead of a c# keyword

Tags: c#, html, razor

I have written a custom html helper for creating checkboxes and I want to apply html attributes as an anonymous type but I can't use the "checked" property of the checkbox because the compiler thinks that I'm referring to the C# keyword:

```
@Html.CustCheckbox(p => p.SomeProperty, scope, htmlAttributes: new { checked = "checked" })
```

Which produces the error:

```
Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.
```

Is there a way around this, so I can still use my above helper. It works fine with other html attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to prefix `checked` with the `@` symbol:

```
@Html.CustCheckbox(p => p.SomeProperty, scope, htmlAttributes: new { @checked = "checked" })
```

From the language specification (Section 2.4.2; emphasis mine):

> The rules for identifiers given in this section correspond exactly to those recommended by the Unicode Standard Annex 31, except that underscore is allowed as an initial character (as is traditional in the C programming language), Unicode escape sequences are permitted in identifiers, **and the “@” character is allowed as a prefix to enable keywords to be used as identifiers.**

Comment: I tried that but I didn't realise that the attribute was being applied to a parent element instead of the input element, so that's why it wasn't working. Nevertheless your answer is correct.

Comment: I'm glad you've spotted your issue @DSF.